# Is available complete project for spring + apache camel + activeMQ + queue integration?

Tags: spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

Can anyone help me to get complete project for spring + apache camel + activeMQ + queue integration?

Answer (score 0):

Install Fuse Tooling in **JBDS(Jboss developer studio 10.x)**.

you can create Fuse project from **File-->new FuseProject**

select spring **mvn archtype** and finish will create sample project